Cross-reference table in R Markdown
Is there a way to cross-reference a table in R Markdown? Please note that I'm not refering to a table of type kable, but the base one, the one you can insert directly from the visual panel.

You need an output format that supports it.  See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html .

Create a new quarto project, any kind will do. In the index.qmd paste the following and render.
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
| A    | B    | C    |
| E    | F    | G    |
| A    | G    | G    |

: My Caption {#tbl-letters}

See @tbl-letters.

Output is the following.

https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html#tables

knitr::kable() isn't used in either example. I removed the bookdown example. Quarto can render RMarkdown tables with cross referencing. Copy and paste the code to try.

Upon execution the output is not the desired.

There are several ways to tweak tables in quarto and with custom float types you can pretty much define and cross reference whatever you want, but ok. Can you show an example of desired output? Perhaps provide data of what you are looking to cross reference.

Sorry if I'm not being clear. Essentially I want to be able, when mentioning a Table X in the content of the document (e.g., "Table X below presents the results..."), to click on "Table X" and be directed, as you probably guessed by now, to Table X. When I try your suggested solution, nothing seems to happen, and I simply see the text "@tbl-letters" on the body of the document and the text "{#tbl-letters}" on the caption of the table. By the way, thank you very much for time @ncraig.

I expanded the answer to describe the process and illustrate the output.

I accepted your answer as a solution. Note that however, for this to work, you have to install the "bookdown" package and include "output: bookdown::pdf_document2: default" in the YAML.

Glad you got it sorted out. Where possible, I suggest moving to quarto. At least from my experience, it is much simpler to use and more robust than the bookdown package.

@ncraig:  I agree it's preferable to bookdown, but I still strongly prefer R Markdown.  It's way easier to debug when you stay in R.
